# Azure AD B2C custom policy SAML with multiple OuputClaims causing AADB2C: An exception has occurred

Tags: saml, azure-ad-b2c, adfs

I am using a custom policy that has a Claims Provider for SAML 2.0 that is integrating with my on-premise ADFS. Below is a snippet of the OutputClaims that I have configured. When I have it configure this way, during the signuporsignin process, B2C throws an error "AADB2C: An exception has occurred.". Looking at the logs in Application Insights, I can see the error during the OutputClaimsTransformationHandler:

""Too many values were encountered for key ""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn"" in the TryGetValue method which can only return a single value. Please use TryGetValues method instead.""

```xml
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="display_name"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="fastpathdemo.com" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="externalIdp"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_email" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_idp" DefaultValue="fastpathdemo.com" />
  </OutputClaims>
```

It seems that I cannot not have two OutputClaims reference the same PartnerClaimType. I have two different claims in my scenario that I need to be set to the same value coming from the SAML claims.

Has anyone ran into this or know why this would be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the ClaimTypeReferenceId and PartnerClaimType values reversed. If you're taking the value that's currently in the "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" claim and want to output it into both the email and extension_email claims it would look like this:

```xml
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="display_name"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="fastpathdemo.com" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="externalIdp"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" PartnerClaimType="extension_email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_idp" DefaultValue="fastpathdemo.com" />
  </OutputClaims>
```